# What's the "correct" HTTP status code for valid request that fail for a valid business reason?

Tags: rest, api-design

Wanted to get your opinion on this, probably there's isn't an absolute right answer, but I want to see what you think is the more correct approach.

If there's nothing structurally wrong with a request (it's in the correct format) and all the fields are valid (field values not too long, required fields have a value etc...) but the call failed because of a business reason, for example "you cannot change a status of task that isn't assigned to you", what should be the response in this case:

1. 200 with a JSON which explains the error:

> ```
> {
>   error: {
>     code :120,
>     message: "you cannot change a status of a task that isn't assigned to you"
>   }
> }
> ```

2. or maybe a 4xx response with a similar body:

> ```
> {
>   error: {
>     code :120,
>     message: "you cannot change a status of a task that isn't assigned to you"
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: You might want to read up the summary on the groups (first digit): *1xx Information, 2xx Success, 3xx Redirect, 4xx Client Error, 5xx Server Error*

Comment: Honestly it depends. In some situations for high-security, they will always return `404` to give an attacker less info.

Comment: this sounds like authorization, maybe 401- unauthorized access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I want to agree with @EJK, the spec he linked is out of date.

The most current one is RFC7231: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1 which changed the meaning of the *old* `403 FORBIDDEN` response status.

**Answer:**

So for the sake of this question `400 BadRequest` should be used, because whoever consumed your service, case being the client, is wrong and can possible fix his request

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
> *will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
> a client error* (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
> message framing, or deceptive request routing).

An example from your own use case:

The client now knows that the error `"you cannot change a status of a task that isn't assigned to you"` is his own fault. And he may even try to issue a different new (valid) request.

Answer (score 2):

403 Forbidden seems like a good match.

From http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4.

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
>   Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If
>   the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public
>   why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason
>   for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make
>   this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not
>   Found) can be used instead.

Thus, option 2, as you have proposed, seems good as it also describes the reason for the failure.